# error with tables "undefined control sequence"

Tags: tables, math-mode, amsart

I am having trouble with creating table in "amsart" environment after I changed from "article". The table does not show boundary and gives an error "undefined control sequence". Am I missing any package or what?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc} \toprule 
        {$q$} & {$5$} & {$6$} & {$7$} & {$8$} & {$9$} & {$10$}\\ \midrule
        {number} & {$9$} & {$20$} & {$48$} & {$115$} & {$286$} & {$719$}\\ \midrule
        {total} & $12$ & $33$ & $385$ & $300$ & $526$ & $2205$
        \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

Comment: I changed your question - removed all unnecessary parts being still able to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the `booktabs` package with `\usepackage{booktabs}`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc} \toprule 
        {$q$} & {$5$} & {$6$} & {$7$} & {$8$} & {$9$} & {$10$}\\ \midrule
        {number} & {$9$} & {$20$} & {$48$} & {$115$} & {$286$} & {$719$}\\ \midrule
        {total} & $12$ & $33$ & $385$ & $300$ & $526$ & $2205$
        \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!